# Are anonymous arrays possible in fortran?

Tags: pointers, fortran, anonymous-types, anonymous

I am trying to create an array of arrays in Fortran.

Something like the following

```
TYPE :: array_of_arrays
   REAL, DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: p => NULL()
END TYPE

TYPE(array_of_arrays), DIMENSION(2) :: some_array
```

So that I can do:

```
REAL, DIMENSION(3), TARGET :: some_vector1 = (/1.0, 2.1, 4.3/)
REAL, DIMENSION(3), TARGET :: some_vector2 = (/3.0, 1.2, 9.6/)

some_array(1)%p => some_vector1
some_array(2)%p => some_vector2

WRITE(*,*) some_array(1)%p ! I see some_vector1
WRITE(*,*) some_array(2)%p ! I see some_vector2
```

Now it's cumbersome for me to actually declare each of these `some_vector` arrays to correspond to each element in my array of arrays.

What I'd like to do is have in a separate subroutine where a temporary vector is set as a target, and that subroutine sets up my array of arrays to point to that temporary vector.

This way I can have anonymous arrays.

However, this doesn't seem to be working and I wonder if first if I am doing something that Fortran doesn't support.

So does Fortran support anonymous arrays, that is (in case I have the terms wrong), an array who can only be accessed through a reference?

Comment: I don't follow.  Guessing wildly, your separate subroutine could ALLOCATE the pointer components such that they pointed at "temporary" storage.  You would need to consider the lifetime of that temporary storage.  Perhaps show the code for what "doesn't seem to be working".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure; as IanH suggests, you can just have the pointer refer to allocated memory directly, rather than refer to a variable; this is one of the few cases where the allocated memory doesn't automatically get deallocated once it goes out of scope.

eg,

```
module arrays


TYPE :: array_of_arrays
   REAL, DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: p => NULL()
END TYPE

contains

subroutine alloc(aa)
    type(array_of_arrays), intent(inout) :: aa(:)
    integer :: i

    allocate( aa(1)%p(1) )
    aa(1) % p = [1.]

    allocate( aa(2)%p(5) )
    aa(2) % p = [ (i, i=1,5) ]

end subroutine alloc

end module arrays



program usearrays
    use arrays

    TYPE(array_of_arrays), DIMENSION(2) :: some_array

    call alloc(some_array)

    WRITE(*,*) some_array(1)%p ! I see some_vector1
    WRITE(*,*) some_array(2)%p ! I see some_vector2

    deallocate( some_array(1) )
    deallocate( some_array(2) )

end program usearrays
```

and running it gives

```
$ gfortran -o arrays arrays.f90 
$ ./arrays 
   1.0000000    
   1.0000000       2.0000000       3.0000000       4.0000000       5.0000000
```

Comment: Yup. That did it. I didn't realize allocating pointers was what I wanted. I had only thought the allocate subroutine was for allocatable array but this makes sense now.

Comment: It isn't obvious that the same syntax should be used for for two notionally (within the language) different operations, but there it is...